# Have anyone here used DAY CQ?

Tags: aem, day-cq

Anyone here develops on DAY CQ? Can advise what is the forum or community to seek for help?
I tried to sign up to their google groups but am not able to do so

Comment: Day has been bought by Adobe. And Day is not an acronym. Try searching for "Adobe CQ" instead.

Answer (score 3):

Day CQ is a Web Content Management platform based on Java and the JCR specification.  Contrary to BoltClock, I would still recommend searching for Day CQ as Adobe does not seem to have really re-branded the Day products.

First I would try searching Day's Documentation at http://docs.day.com.  Dacare is Day's hub for all of their support and such at http://www.day.com/content/daycare.html, you can find links to support groups, documentation, downloads and etcetera from there.

Answer (score 3):

Google Groups is the right forum: https://groups.google.com/group/day-communique

Answer (score 1):

Day developer web site: http://dev.day.com/content/ddc.html

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a forum to the one you can go to, it's located under:

http://forums.adobe.com/community/digital_marketing_suite/cq5

So take a look around a see if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think the google groups is the most useful, the yahoo one constantly has spam..

[Google Groups - day-communique](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/day-communique)

[Yahoo Groups - day-communique](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/Day-Communique/)

Other useful stuff...

Current Widgets API -(dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html)
 - used when adding widgets to your dialogs (I don't have enough rep to post as link)

Answer (score 0):

The forums for developers working with CQ5 are rather scattered about.  I have bookmarked this one: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/jcr-crx/, which has seen 22 postings since the first of the year.

There is also a much more forum for users of the open source Apache Jackrabbit, which underlies CQ5's repository: http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.jackrabbit.user.

Answer (score 0):

As Atigar says the Adobe CQ5 users forum is at http://forums.adobe.com/community/digital_marketing_suite/cq5

CQ5 is based on three Apache Software Foundation projects:

http://felix.apache.org/ - the Apache Felix OSGi framework. In general, you don't need to know much about it to develop with CQ5.

http://jackrabbit.apache.org/ - the Apache Jackrabbit JCR content repository, the CRX content repository that CQ5 runs on uses the same core code, with some extensions.

http://sling.apache.org/ - the Apache Sling web framework which CQ5 uses to process HTTP requests, including mapping them to scripts or servlets. Understanding the Sling way of doing things helps a lot in understanding CQ.

These 3 projects all have user mailing lists as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is a LinkedIn group for enterprise users of CQ/AEM as well. See the link:

[LinkedIn Adobe CQ Enterprise Users Group](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Adobe-CQ-Enterprise-Users-Group-794067)